# MS Access 2003 - Really simple query

Tags: ms-access, replication, backend, ms-access-2003

If I try to duplicate an access file (this file is split into mdb and be mdb, and also has mde files), by importing everything into a brand new access application, why won't the table links work? Everytime I click anything it says that the tables cannot be found

Probably so simple it's not worth asking on here, but ....?

Comment: Are the linked tables somewhere else like a SQL Server.... how is that connection configured for your new Access database?

Comment: When you were running the import/link process, did you see any table links?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you import a link table in the usual way (File->Get External data), the links are imported not the tables themselves. You need to import the tables from the back-end.

Comment: He is not asking about the actual table objects themselves.  He is asking for the links.  your method would actually copy the tables to the new FE mdb which is not what he wants.

Comment: I am not sure about that, the OP says "everything".